# Cleared Clipboard is not null

Tags: c#, winforms, clipboard

I want to check if the Clipboard consists of a data and if not, let the "Paste" Button be enabled. But unfortunately, even after I clear the Clipboard it still doesn't show it's null. I am working with Windows Forms.

I manually clear the clipboard:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Clipboard.Clear();
        }
```

and then I add the following code to the Form LoadEvent:

```
if (Clipboard.GetDataObject() != null)
            {
                this.pn1_BtnPaste.Enabled = true;                  
            }
```

And it makes a button enabled which is weird to me. Can anybody explain why is that happening?

**EDIT:**
Because I got understood wrong, let me change the code to make it more clear:

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Clipboard.Clear();

            if (Clipboard.GetDataObject() != null)
            {
                this.pn1_BtnPaste.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
                this.pn1_BtnPaste.Enabled = false;
        }
```

I click the "button2" and the "pn1_BtnPaste" is enabled anyway.

Comment: To be clear - it sounds like the `if (Clipboard.GetDataObject() != null)` check runs on form load, ie _before_ you're calling `.Clear()`?  You've also got no code to _disable_ the button?

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you are trying to accomplish here.  `pn1_BtnPaste.Enabled = true;` will indeed make the button enable, why is that weird?

Comment: Ok I didn't express myself clearly enough I guess. Please check my edit. The button remains enabled altough I clear the clipboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data can appear on the clipboard at any time.  The Application.Idle event is a decent way to update the button state:

```
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        Application.Idle += Application_Idle;
    }
```

You have to unsubscribe it again when the window closes to be on the safe side:

```
    protected override void OnFormClosed(FormClosedEventArgs e) {
        Application.Idle -= Application_Idle;
        base.OnFormClosed(e);
    }
```

Clipboard.GetDataObject() does not work the way you think it does, it never returns null.  If you want to handle *any* data then you can write the event handler like this:

```
    private void Application_Idle(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        PasteButton.Enabled = Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetFormats().Length > 0;
    }
```

But it is pretty likely you'll find out that handling every possible format is lot let practical than you assumed.